# How can I call a remote User Defined Function with Parameters?

Tags: sql-server-2005

We have one SQL server which contains a link to another server that is on a different box. I would like to create a user-defined-function on ServerA which returns the value of the udf on ServerB, however SQL is telling me that `Remote function calls are not allowed within a function.`

Is there a way around this?

The udf does have a parameter, so I cannot use `OPENQUERY`. I thought I had it working by using `sp_executesql`, however although this works in a blank query window, it doesn't work from a user-defined function.

```
declare @someValue bit

exec ServerB.MyDatabase.dbo.sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT @someValue = dbo.[SomeUDF](@id)',
    N'@id int, @someValue bit OUTPUT', 
    @id=@id, @someValue=@someValue OUTPUT

select @someValue
```

The entire function gets called as part of a query, so I don't think I can use a stored procedure

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE dbo.SomeUDF(Id) = 1
```

Comment: Late to this thread, but I'm looking to do something similar. I found this and will try it after I look around some more.
http://developer.sheikhharis.com/2012/11/call-user-defined-function-on-linked.html

Comment: Hi, and welcome to DBA.SE. Link-only answers are frowned upon all across the Stack Exchange network - your post loses all its value as soon as that link goes dead. Please sum up your findings in your answer (by [edit]ing it) _if_ they work. (In general, please avoid posting solutions you haven't tried.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use OPENQUERY. You just have to use dynamic SQL to build the OPENQUERY call

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(linkedServerName, 
                          ''SELECT @someValue = dbo.[SomeUDF](' + CAST(@id etc) + ')'')';
EXEC (@sql)
```

However, you can't build this into a larger query on the local server. 
UDFs + linked servers + parameters just don't play nice together...

Comment: Hrrrm so you're saying there's no way to use a UDF from a linked server as part of a larger query? I figured if anyone knew of a way around that you would. Thank you though.

Comment: @Rachel: AFAIK, no.

Comment: @gbn: No you can't, exec requires a stored procedure, not a table-valued function.

Comment: :@Quandary: what do you mean? `EXEC (@SQL)` execute the string as a query. No UDFs ndded